# How to get pre-signed url with AWS.ManagedUpload

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I'm uploading file to AWS S3 with AWS.S3.ManagedUpload. Everything was simple until I want to obtain pre-signed URL for uploaded file.

I'm creating AWS.S3.ManagedUpload, and fire send method.

```
   const params = {
        Bucket: process.env.S3_BUCKET_NAME,
        Key: fileKey,
        Body: fileStream,
      }

     const upload = new AWS.S3.ManagedUpload({ params })

      upload.send((err, data) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err)
        }
        // handle successful upload
      })
    }
```

As a result I receive object with non-singed url. So it is accessible only if bucket is public which I want avoid.

Comment: Sorry the off-topic, but how do you send credentials to ManagedUpload ? I'm trying to use it, but can't find any working example.

Answer (score 0):

I found simple solution. You need to use AWS.S3.getSignedUrl when upload is done.

```
upload.send((err, data) => {
  if (err) {
    // handle error 
  }
  const signedUrl = s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', params) 
  ...
```

Where params is `{ Bucket, Key, Expires }`